# Change the max value of nvarchar in SQL database without deleting and rebuilding the table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, alter-table, nvarchar

Currently I have a SQL database with a column value of nvarchar(255) I need to change this to be nvarchar(600) when I edit it in the SQL visual studio on the server a warning pops up and states that the table must be deleted and rebuilt for my changes to be made. I **DO NOT** want to have to do this on the advice on the developer who built the program in the first place. (He is unable to make the change for me at this time).

I have seen a lot of answers that advise to Uncheck "Prevent saving changes that require ..." in the settings but again this is something I am reluctant to do on the advise of many others on this site and elsewhere.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to change this max value without having to delete and rebuild the table?

Would a simple `ALTER` statement work? The field does not allow NULL values would something like this work?

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.myTable
ALTER COLUMN myColumn VARCHAR(600)
```

Comment: Append `NOT NULL` option to the end of statement. F5.

Comment: @IvanStarostin Msg 5074, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The object 'DF_myTable_myColumn' is dependent on column 'myColumn'.
Msg 4922, Level 16, State 9, Line 1
ALTER TABLE ALTER COLUMN myColumn failed because one or more objects access this column. - I have replaced the names in the actual statement btw.

Comment: Previous developer stated I will "need to change the table type"? :S

Comment: It's saying that you have `default constraint` on that column. Drop it before, add it back afterwards.

Comment: I have to admit I am a bit of a novice when it comes to this kind of db management and i'm not really sure on how to do that.

Comment: What is the default value for that column? You should see it in visual studio.

Comment: default value for this particular column is a string like "foo"

Comment: I haven't got around to trying this yet but when I do I will let you know, thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SET XACT_ABORT ON

BEGIN TRAN

ALTER TABLE dbo.myTable
DROP CONSTRAINT DF_myTable_myColumn

ALTER TABLE dbo.myTable
ALTER COLUMN myColumn VARCHAR(600) NOT NULL

ALTER TABLE dbo.myTable
ADD CONSTRAINT DF_myTable_myColumn DEFAULT('foo') FOR myColumn

COMMIT TRAN
```